# Scala - Play! 2 - Generic Crud

Tags: json, scala, generics, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a generic crud controller, but I'm falling into a json problem.

I have an implicit read and write for each of my domain objects and since my crud controller is "generic", I'm passing T for it, which causes no implicit converter found for type T.

Here is my TestController

```
object AddressController extends Controller with CrudController[Address, AddressServiceModule] {
```

}

and this is my CrudController

```
trait CrudController[T, K <: GenericServiceModule[T]] extends Controller {

  var service: K = _

  def get(uuid: String) = Action.async {
    val future = service.genericService.getById(UUID.fromString(uuid))
    future.map {
      case Some(t) => Ok(Json.toJson(t))
      case None => NotFound
    }.recover {
      case t =>
        Logger.error("Something went wrong", t)
        InternalServerError(t.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

then I got

```
No Json serializer found for type T.
```

As I said, I have a read and write for my Address model

```
implicit val addressReads = Json.reads[Address]
implicit val addressWrites = Json.writes[Address]
```

But since converters are verified at compile time, I have no idea how to solve this scenario. No chance to write 10, 20 crud controllers with the same logic.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Just for test, I changed the Ok(Json.toJson(t)) for Ok(t.toString) then I got another problem...

a NullPointer on my service

```
var service: K = _
```

My GenericServiceModule is the following:

```
trait GenericServiceModule[T] {

  def genericService: GenericCommonService[T]

  /**
   * Common Services
   * @tparam T
   */
  trait GenericCommonService[T] {
    def getById(uuid: UUID): Future[Option[T]]
    def deleteById(uuid: UUID): Future[ResultSet]
    def insert(t: T): (UUID, Future[ResultSet])
    def update(uuid: UUID, t: T): (UUID, Future[ResultSet])
  }

}
```

and the AddressServiceModule which I'm passing to the AddressController is the following:

```
trait AddressServiceModule extends GenericServiceModule[Address] with CassandraService {

  object genericService extends GenericCommonService[Address] {

    override def getById(uuid: UUID): Future[Option[Address]] = {
      Address.select.where(_.id eqs uuid).one()
    }
}
```

is there a way to inject anyhow this Service through my CrudController?

Comment: What is `service: K` supposed to be exactly?

Comment: I'm passing AddressServiceModule in the AddressController which I figure out gives me null :S

Comment: Where do you define the `Reads` and `Writes` of `Address`? In the companion object, or `AddressServiceModule` ?

Comment: in the companion object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using some sort of trait for each companion object to require the `Reads` and `Writes`?

```
trait CrudObject[T] {
    val reads: Reads[T]
    val writes: Writes[T]
}
```

For example:

```
object Address extends CrudObject[Address] {
    implicit val reads: Reads[Address] = Json.reads[Address]
    implicit val writes: Writes[Address] = Json.writes[Address]

    // other code ..
}
```

Then in your generic controller, require references to the companion object (marked by the `CrudObject` trait) and the `GenericServiceModule`. This won't quite make the implicit resolution work, but once you have that reference, you can then rely on inheritance to make the `Reads` and `Writes` available within the controller.

```
trait CrudController[T] extends Controller {

  def service: GenericServiceModule[T]

  def companion: CrudObject[T]

  implicit def reads: Reads[T] = companion.reads

  implicit def writes: Reads[T] = companion.writes

  def get(uuid: String) = Action.async {
    val future = service.genericService.getById(UUID.fromString(uuid))
    future.map {
      case Some(t) => Ok(Json.toJson(t))
      case None => NotFound
    }.recover {
      case t =>
        Logger.error("Something went wrong", t)
        InternalServerError(t.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

Then your implementation could look like:

```
object AddressController extends CrudController[Address] {

   def service = AddressServiceModule

   def companion = Address

}
```

Comment: hmm probably this solves my 2 problems, the null that I got passing the service through the crud controller and the json parser... I'll test it and let you know

Comment: it works! The CrudObject did the trick and also solved my service injection through composition. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I have a question based on your answer. Today this design is working fine, but I have to create a custom converter with JsPath etc. In the unlift function. for example (unlift(Address.apply _)) it gives me an error of type mismatch, expecting NotInferedA => Option[NotInferedB] but actual is CrudObject[Nothing] => CrudObject[Nothing]. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @ThiagoPereira It's hard to tell without more code. Perhaps ask a new question with more information?

Comment: thanks for your help, here we go: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370831/play-custom-json-with-generic-crud)