# Play - Custom Json with Generic Crud

Tags: json, scala, generics, playframework

I have a Crud Controller in my application which works perfectly with JsonInception, but fail with a custom json converter.

Follow the given case class:

```
case class Validity(id: Option[UUID], objectType: String, since: DateTime, until: DateTime, objectId: UUID, validityTargetId: UUID, validityTargetType: String)
```

I have an object companion as follow:

```
object Validity extends CrudObject[Validity] {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Validity]
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[Validity]
}
```

Where my CrudObject is a trait with the given code:

```
trait CrudObject[T] {
  val reads: Reads[T]
  val writes: Writes[T]
}
```

This is needed since I'm working in a Generic Crud. Without this, Play is unable to find any implicit converter.

So my Generic Crud Controller, is something like this:

```
trait CrudController[T] extends Controller {

  def service: ServiceModule[T]
  def companion: CrudObject[T]

  def search...
  def insert...

  implicit def reads: Reads[T] = companion.reads
  implicit def writes: Writes[T] = companion.writes
```

and for each controller, I have the follow:

```
object ValidityController extends CrudController[Validity] {
  override def service: GenericServiceModule[Validity] = ServiceModule
  override def companion: CrudObject[Validity] = Validity
}
```

Ok, with this design in mind, as I said, works perfectly, I need to design a custom json converter. Yes, I know, it's pretty simple, but something is happening and I don't know how to get rid of that.

Now I'm trying to do the following:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[Validity] = (
      (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "objectType").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "since").read[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "until").read[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "objectId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "validityTargetId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "validityTargetType").read[String]
    )(unlift(Validity.apply _))
```

and it gives me:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (NotInferedA) => Option[NotInferedB], actual: (CrudObject[Nothing]) => CrudObject[Nothing]
```

I believe this is happen cuz CrudObject is a trait and does not have apply and unapply.

Anyway, removing CrudObject gives me a similar error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (NotInferedA) => Option[NotInferedB], actual: (Option[UUID], String, DateTime, DateTime, UUID, UUID, String) => Validity
```

but even if I can solve this, I can't imagine living without CrudObject due my GenericCrud.

Any Thoughts?

PS: Thanks to @m-z who has been giving me some assist through stackoverflow =)

**UPDATE**

I'm almost there with this approach:

```
implicit object validityFormat extends Format[Validity] {
    override def writes(o: Validity): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> JsString(o.id.getOrElse(null).toString),
        "objectType" -> JsString(o.objectType),
        "since" -> JsString(o.since.toString),
        "until" -> JsString(o.since.toString),
        "objectId" -> JsString(o.objectId.toString),
        "validityTargetId" -> JsString(o.validityTargetId.toString),
        "validityTargetType" -> JsString(o.validityTargetType))
    }

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Validity] = {
      JsSuccess(Validity(
        (json \ "id").as[Option[UUID]],
        (json \ "objectType").as[String],
        (json \ "since").as[DateTime],
        (json \ "until").as[DateTime],
        (json \ "objectId").as[UUID],
        (json \ "validityTargetId").as[UUID],
        (json \ "validityTargetType").as[String])
      )
    }
  }
```

Using this way, which is different from documentation [Scala Combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ScalaJsonCombinators), I don't get the previous error, which is good, no type mismatch =)

Now I'm working out on to figure out how to convert to UUID and DateTime.

**UPDATE**

I did an example that works, but I accepted the @m-z answer because there are less boilerplate than mine, but both worked fine. The big difference is, in my approach I needed to provide some custom converters for DateTime and for UUID, whereas @m-z approach you don't!

```
implicit object UUIDFormatter extends Format[UUID] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[UUID] = {
      val uuid = json.validate[String]
      JsSuccess(UUID.fromString(uuid.get))
    }

    override def writes(o: UUID): JsValue = {
      JsString(o.toString)
    }
  }

  implicit object DateTimeFormatter extends Format[DateTime] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[DateTime] = {
      val datetime = json.validate[Long]
      JsSuccess(new DateTime(datetime.get))
    }

    override def writes(o: DateTime): JsValue = {
      JsNumber(o.getMillis)
    }
  }

  implicit object validityFormat extends Format[Validity] {
    override def writes(o: Validity): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> JsString(o.id.getOrElse(null).toString),
        "objectType" -> JsString(o.objectType),
        "since" -> JsNumber(o.since.getMillis),
        "until" -> JsNumber(o.since.getMillis),
        "objectId" -> JsString(o.objectId.toString),
        "validityTargetId" -> JsString(o.validityTargetId.toString),
        "validityTargetType" -> JsString(o.validityTargetType))
    }

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Validity] = {
      JsSuccess(Validity(
        (json \ "id").as[Option[UUID]],
        (json \ "objectType").as[String],
        (json \ "since").as[DateTime],
        (json \ "until").as[DateTime],
        (json \ "objectId").as[UUID],
        (json \ "validityTargetId").as[UUID],
        (json \ "validityTargetType").as[String])
      )
    }
```

Comment: yes, it's a java.util.UUID and indeed I have to convert those types. Reading the documentation, they use apply _ for Reads and unapply for Writes. Anyway, I'll try to work out more on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems here, but neither of them are relevant to generics, because you're dealing with the concrete type `Validity`.

First, the last argument using `Reads` combinators should be `(Validity.apply _)`. You would only use `unlift` with `Writes`.

Second, the types in the combinators must map to the types in your `Validity` class.

```
implicit val reads: Reads[Validity] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[UUID] and    // readNullable reads to Option
  (JsPath \ "objectType").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "since").read[DateTime] and
  (JsPath \ "until").read[DateTime] and
  (JsPath \ "objectId").read[UUID] and
  (JsPath \ "validityTargetId").read[UUID] and
  (JsPath \ "validityTargetType").read[String]
)(Validity.apply _)
```

`Reads` already exist for `UUID` and `DateTime`, so this should work okay.

Similarly, `Writes[Validity]` would look like this:

```
implicit val writes: Writes[Validity] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").writeNullable[UUID] and
  (JsPath \ "objectType").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "since").write[DateTime] and
  (JsPath \ "until").write[DateTime] and
  (JsPath \ "objectId").write[UUID] and
  (JsPath \ "validityTargetId").write[UUID] and
  (JsPath \ "validityTargetType").write[String]
)(unlift(Validity.unapply))
```

Comment: Indeed there was nothing wrong with the generics approach. The type mismatch I got was due the wrong types I was passing, but doing the right way, your way hehe works!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I Think that your case class has an option parameter your Reads must have readnullable in the optional parameters must be like this , I'm not sure with UIID and String

```
case class Validity(id: Option[UUID], objectType: String, since: DateTime, until: DateTime, objectId: UUID, validityTargetId: UUID, validityTargetType: String)

implicit val reads: Reads[Validity] = (
      (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[UIID] and
      (JsPath \ "objectType").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "since").read[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "until").read[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "objectId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "validityTargetId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "validityTargetType").read[String]
    )(unlift(Validity.apply _))
```

Comment: changing from Long to DateTime as @m-z wrote, works fine! thank you.